# Why can I index a key in both ascending and descending order in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

I can give the same key both ascending and descending index as below:

```
db.hw1_1.ensureIndex({answer:-1})
db.hw1_1.ensureIndex({answer:1})
```

And you can see that they are working at backend:

```
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "answer" : -1 }, "ns" : "m101.hw1_1", "name" : "answer_-1" }
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "answer" : 1 }, "ns" : "m101.hw1_1", "name" : "answer_1" }
```

Does it make any sense to have both orders of index at the same time on the same key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really doesn't make much sense to to this as the indexes can be used equally to "sort" in either order as it were. That said, there is nothing intrinsically wrong with doing this that should stop you from creating the index. Who knows, maybe you intend to remove one "after" creating the other.

But considering that you would be maintaining two indexes for exactly the same thing, there is the consideration of additional write overhead as well as the obvious additional disk space

But the order of processing will work both ways, and the first available index will always be chosen unless it is specifcically "hinted" at.

For a practical example, create some documents:

```js
{ "answer" : 1 }
{ "answer" : 2 }
{ "answer" : 3 }
```

Then create an index:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "answer": -1 })
```

Query with explain:

```js
db.collection.find({},{_id:0}).sort({ answer: -1 }).explain()
```

Will of course select that index that was created, and when creating another index:

```js
db.collection.ensureIndex({ "answer": 1 })
```

Issue the query with the "ascending" sort order:

```js
db.collection.find({},{_id:0}).sort({ answer: 1 }).explain()
```

You will see that the orginal "answer_-1" index is still selected.

So it really is all down to a matter of how you use the index. If you generally want the results by "decending" key then do it that way or otherwise do the reverse.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to thumb up, anyway thanks for the detailed answer!